# Sending images over a socket and displaying it

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I am trying to send an image from a server to the client and then make the client display it with show(), but i'm having some problems.
this is the server code that sends the image:

```
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
        if not os.path.exists(r'C:\screens'):
            os.makedirs(r'C:\screens')
        im.save(r'C:\screens\screen.jpg')
        data = open(r'C:\screens\screen.jpg', 'r')
        data = data.read()
        client_socket.send(str(data))
```

Now, obviously i can't send a file through a socket so i have send it as a string, but then, i don't know how to use show() in the client because you can't use show() on a string, and I have no idea how to pull this off.
As you can see im pretty much a beginner in python so if the solution is simple and straightforward I'm sorry about that.
i'll appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Python 2 or 3? (edit: python 2.7, was in the tags, sorry) In any case: an image file is almost always not text, so don't treat it as such.

- this also means you have to read the image data as binary instead of in text mode, so use `data = open("image.jpg", "rb").read()`
- don't convert to `str` before sending it over the socket, send the binary (bytes) directly instead.
- on the receiving end (your client?) you `recv` the bytes from the socket. I guess you can use `Image.frombytes` to directly create an image back from it and show that. Alternatively, write the bytes you got from the socket to a new file (make sure to open it with "wb" binary mode) and `Image.open()` that file.

Comment: He has the python-2.7 tag, so he's probably using Python 2.

Comment: Im using Python 2.7, now i canged it to 'rb' and it seems to work better, but about the Image.frombytes - it seems it takes 3 arguments - (mode, size, and unpacked pixel data), and i have no idea how i can know those three. (im even not sure what the last one means). How can i know those arguments?

Comment: Okay forget about ``Image.frombytes`` (it is for raw image data, which is not what you're dealing with here), just save your image bytes and use ``Image.open`` to read it. To avoid having to create a file you should be able to use ``io.BytesIO`` as well to directly read from your in memory bytes buffer.